# Django Model not automatically creating ID

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am attempting to save a simple device model, which has three fields, username, device_name and manufacturer.

Looking at the model in the Database, an ID field was added as the Primary Key. This field should auto increment.

After reading some documentation, I have tried to recreate the following even:

```
Auto-incrementing primary keys¶

If a model has an AutoField — an auto-incrementing primary key — then that 
auto-incremented value will be calculated and saved as an attribute on your 
object the first time you call save():

>>> b2 = Blog(name='Cheddar Talk', tagline='Thoughts on cheese.')
>>> b2.id     # Returns None, because b doesn't have an ID yet.
>>> b2.save()
>>> b2.id     # Returns the ID of your new object.
```

When doing that for my device model:

```
>>> d = Device("username123", "device12", "manufact12")
>>> d.id
>>> 'username123'
```

If I attempt to save this model it will give me the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'username123'
```

So it is trying to save 'username123' as the ID. If I create the following device:

```
>>> d = Device("1", "username123", "device12", "manufact12")
```

It creates the device with no problem.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Edit: After seeing the first reply, it seems that my post was not clear. Here is my model from Django:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

It does not have an ID. As I said in my post, when I try to create the model without the ID (as I would expect to do) it gives me an error. If I explicitly state an ID it works, but as you said, that is not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65760979/django-rest-framework-with-mongodb-not-creating-auto-field-primary-key-id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to understand what does `auto incrementing` mean. It means it's an integer that increases by itself so you don't need to bother assigning a new integer to it every time you create a database record. If you insert the first record, database would automatically give it id as `1`. Next time you inserts a records, database gives it id `2` and so on.

You were trying to give `username123` to the id field, which there's no way for django(and for anybody) to know what's the next available id for `username123`.

So the best action is: never explicitly give an id to a model object, because your database will generate one for you. I hope that makes sense.

**Edit:**

You should NEVER create an object this way:

```
d = Device("username123", "device12", "manufact12")
```

It's a common bad practice for sql statement and django as well: not specify which field to take which value. If your model changed later, you would assign the value to the wrong field. Always do this:

```
d = Device(field1="username123",
           field2="device12",
           field3="manufact12")
```

Also for completeness, the error you had was telling you: since you didn't specify which value assign to which field, I would assign them in sequence, so the first value should assign to `id`. However, since `id` field is an integer field(auto increment), I would try to use `int()` to convert it to integer and store the value. But apparently `int("username123")` is invalid statement, hence the error.

Comment: Yup, your Edit fixed the problem. Interesting. I still don't really understand why it was either A) Wanting me to specify the ID, or B) Giving me an error if I didn't specify the ID. None of the Django documentation talks about specifying the ID, as if it is created when you save your model. Heck, even the example I gave above from Django docs shows what I just described.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the complete answer. Very well done! I don't have the REP to upvote you, but you earned it!